# Why does changing the position of a fragment in my layout cause my app to crash?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

My app simply has two buttons and a space where a ListFragment is loaded in. The app runs as desired when the buttons are defined to be at the top in the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/displayfragment1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_fragment1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/displayfragment2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_fragment2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="0px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However when I move the fragment layout above the buttons, as below, the app crashes on startup.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/myfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="0px" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/displayfragment1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_fragment1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/displayfragment2"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_fragment2" />
    </LinearLayout>       

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the only change I am making to cause this crash and so I assume this must be the problem?

Comment: Not the main issue, but use `0dp` instead of `0px`. Also, what does your LogCat say?

Comment: I think you might need to show us the relevant Java code too. :)

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponenentInfo{com.mattlefleur.fragmentstutorial/com.mattlefleur.fragmentstutorial.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Comment: If you're absolutely sure you're doing `LinearLayout layout =  (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.myfragment);` then clean your project.

Comment: @A--C Wow, that was easy! Cleaned the project and it worked instantly :) Why was that necessary though? Thank you for the help.

Comment: Eclipse is annoying sometimes, that's why :)

Comment: Haha! :) Can you post your comment as an answer so I can mark this as answered please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember to clean your project (Project -> Clean) after changing stuff involving `R` (especially layout stuff). Sometimes Eclipse will "forget" to modify `R` to reflect the changes (or modifies it incorrectly as seemed to be the issue here) and odd issues occur.